# How to write a bash function that calls a command with the same name?

Tags: bash, zsh

I want to write a wrapper around a command that checks a condition before executing the underlying command. I can't figure out how to execute the underlying command without invoking the current function.

```
function npm() {
  # if a yarn.lock file exists in the current dir or a parent dir then exit 1
  npm "$@" # otherwise run the actual npm command, not this same function
}
```

I can't hard code the whole path to npm because it varies depending on which version of npm I have active at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
command npm ...
```

where `command` is called a *precommand modifier*, see https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Precommand-Modifiers